# What comes under onTabChanged in an onTabChangedListener?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Consider the following scenario:
2 tabs in a parent activity. Each of them has a separate activity (please don't go about saying that this is deprecated and use fragments, I already know that). Now if I add a "OnTabChangeListener" and implement the abstract function "onTabChanged", **in which cases will that function be called**?
Only when the tabs are switched, i.e. I go from tab1 to tab2 (or the other way around) or also when from tab1/tab2 I go to another activity(not tab2/tab1, but something entirely different).
And is there a way to change the default behaviour?

Comment: If you're directly starting a separate `Activity` manually, then I don't imagine the listener would fire. What happened when you tested it? Furthermore, if you don't know what the default behavior is, how do you know that you want to change it?

Comment: The separate activity which I am starting is started from **within** one of the activities hosted by the tabHost. So does that come under "onTabChanged"? Also, I want to change the default behaviour irrespective of what it is. (If it is A, then I want to know how to achieve B; and the reverse case too).

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you meant. What happened when you tested it?

Comment: The method wasn't called when going to another activity.

Comment: In that case, to get the other behavior, I'd say the simplest thing to do would be to manually call whatever code you have the listener running whenever you call `startActivity()` yourself.